# Syntax Highlighting of Common Lisp User Defined Macros in Emacs

Tags: macros, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I would like to start writing a few simple Domain Specific Languages in Common Lisp and would like the names of macros I define to be highlighted as if they were Common Lisp functions or macros (in Emacs).

Below is a simple example which is not precisely the code I am hoping to write but is an MWE that shows the kind of functionality I desire.

```
(defmacro class* (class-name superclasses slots)
  (let ((slot-declarations
     (loop for slot in slots collecting
          (list slot :accessor slot :initform nil))))
    `(defclass ,class-name ,superclasses ,slot-declarations)))

(class* graph () (nodes edges))
```

What I would like is for `class*` in the *second* form to show up in magenta (given the default colours in my Emacs installation) and `graph` should be highlighted in blue.

I have seen some examples of how to adjust syntax highlighting for LaTeX but I could not extend those to work for me in Common Lisp.

Many thanks.

Comment: This seems a bit off-topic here on TeX.SE, maybe it is better suited for https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not connected to TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, my apologies - I only just realised this.  This is my first time asking a question in StackExchange and I didn't realise I was in the TeX group.